# How to use a struct object for multiple files?

Tags: c++, oop, struct, config

So, I want to use a configuration struct object across multiple project files.
The struct consists of thing like FPS, gameMode, volume, foreground_color, background_color,
and I want to be able to change these while running the project.
If one class changes some configuration, I want the other classes to notice it too.

Whats the best approach

1. Making an object of struct and pass it as reference to all classes that require it?
   (but it would to be too much work to pass it to so many classes)
2. Declaring the struct object in a header file as extern variable providing it external linkage
   (I am not sure if its the right approach or if I can even edit extern variable)
3. Some other way I am unaware of ?

Comment: Using dependency injection (1) could simplify writing unit tests for your code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This sounds like "observer pattern" to me.

Comment: Service locator pattern may also help you.

Comment: You don't need external linkage. Define your "configuration" as a class (or struct) and put it in its own header file. Then include that file from everywhere it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few suggestions.

## Step 1: Define your configuration as a class in its own header

```
#pragma once

class Config
{

    // config stuff goes here, get, set etc

};
```

## Step 2: Use Service Locator pattern to "get" the Config from any class which needs it

This works by providing static methods on a class which you can use to get a default config, or set your own config, if you so wish to do so.

```
// Some variation of this

#pragma once

class ServiceLocator
{

    static void setConfig(const Config& config)
    {
        myConfig = std::make_unique<Config>(config);
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<Config> getConfig() const
    {
        if(!myConfig)
        {
            myConfig = std::make_unique<Config>();
        }
        return myConfig;
    }

    private:

    static std::unique_ptr<Config> myConfig;
};
```

## Step 3: Define some kind of Observer pattern to implement something happening when changes are made

This is more difficult to sketch out because I don't know what you want.

You can read more about that here. If you can provide me with a concrete use case I can sketch something out for you.

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer